# Getting "Cannot invoke "java.net.URI.getScheme()" because "uri" is null" in pom.xml while compiling Spring mvc example

Tags: spring, pom.xml

I am getting this error in my `pom.xml` for my SpringMVC project in Eclipse:
`"Cannot invoke "java.net.URI.getScheme()" because "uri" is null"`

Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you were not getting this error earlier, when you loaded the maven project into the IDE, move the `pom.xml` content to a notepad, save the empty `pom.xml`, let the IDE try processing the empty `pom.xml` and paste the content back and save it.
Somehow STS IDE starts PMS-ing all by itself. Worked for me - Spring Tool Suite 4.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the project from Eclipse without deleting the contents from disk. Import the project again and wait for build(if it is automatic) and clean the project. It should work and worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply as I'm not sure if you are using Maven; This error occurred when I renamed a maven project under the Refactor menu option in Eclipse. To fix it, inside of the Project Explorer, right click on the project and select:

> Maven -> Update Project ... -> Select Force Update of Snapshots/Releases then OK. It should fix the issue.

[image: Update Maven Project Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be caused by renaming or deleting maven project folder outside the Eclipse then removing those missing items inside Eclipse. Later you re-import the project back to Eclipse with a different project folder name.

If this is your case, the easiest way to solve the problem is to remove the .metadata folder in your Eclipse workspace and create a new one. Import the maven project and this time everything should be fine.

If removing the .metadata folder is not an option, you can try the following steps:

1. Build the maven project in Eclipse.
2. If there is a popup error message like "project_loc:XXX not found", go to
   <your_workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/
3. open the file "build-<your_maven_project_name>.launch"
4. edit the following line:

<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="${project_loc:XXXXXXXXXX}" / >

replace XXXXXXXXXX with your new project folder name, save the file, close Eclipse, reopen it, problem should be solved.